# How can I redo a retracted duplicate flag?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-answers

I have retracted a duplicate flag to correct it.

But now I can't reflag for duplicate.

Is there a solution to apply again the duplicate flag?

Here is the question:
[How to implement decision tree with c# (visual studio 2008) - Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889301/how-to-implement-decision-tree-with-c-sharp-visual-studio-2008-help/3889544#3889544)

That I'd like to flag for duplicate of:
[How to implement an interactive decision tree in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249079/how-to-implement-an-interactive-decision-tree-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand these answers. Does this mean that the flag remains in the queue and that someone can possibly validate it?

Comment: Not the flag stays in the queue, the flagged post is and reviewers can cast close votes if they sees the need to (they can close for different reasons than your flag (e.g. not as a duplicate, but as "too broad"). Your flag is gone and you won't get it marked as declined/helpful/disputed, when the post has been handled.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Is there now a way to have the question flagged as duplicate?

Comment: Not for you, no. You've casted your only flag you have for that post. Every person has only one flag per post to avoid someone re-flagging a post when the old flag has been declined. You still can leave a comment with a link to the dupe and others can read, agree and then flag the post on their own.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I left a comment for others.